# constantly resizing iframe to contents via Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

if found this solution on the web that re-sizes the iFrame on load. I was wondering how I can do this by setting an loop that constantly check's the active iframe's content size then resize it instantly

any ideas on how to do this on Jquery? Thanks!

Comment: Ooof.  Dynamic iFrame resizing is miserable, especially if the page you are trying to load is too big/takes too long to load.  Some browsers time out, giving you wrong numbers.

Comment: just as ive expected. anyway, do you have a sample of this Robert?

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting the code which changes the size of the iframe within the iframe page. When the iframe page loads, it can use jQuery to search for DOM elements within it's parent window. The javascript to do with would look like:

```
$(function () {
    var height = $(document).height();
    $('iframe', window.parent.document).height(height + 'px');
});
```

Comment: i was more on resizing the height of the iframe when the content of it changes its own height.